# What are the limits and effects of Boosting Sitecore Users

Tags: concurrent-users

When using the client's Sitecore license, if the client reaches the maximum number of Concurrent Users they are directed to a page where they can either *exit*, *add users* or *kick off a user*:

[image]

The "Add users" option (formerly "Boost users"), grants the ability to temporarily add more concurrent users. When a user selects this option, the user is redirected to the following page where they can enter the number of concurrent users to temporarily add to the license:

[image]

#### Questions

Looking at [Sitecore's documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/login/kick_off_or_add_a_user#_Increase_the_number), I don't see anything that explains what the actual effects of "boosting" concurrent users are. Specifically, I am looking for the following:

1. What is the maximum number of users that you can boost the site by?
2. How long does the boost remain in effect, i.e. what is the duration of time that "temporarily" describes?
3. How often can this feature be used?
4. Is there any additional charge to the client for using this feature?
5. Are their any negative side-effects to be aware of when using this feature?

***Side-note:*** I apologize for not simply testing this feature myself, but I am hesitent to play around with a client's Sitecore license. Rather than ask support, I thought this would be good information to make available to the community. Cheers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It lasts 24 hours, no charge and the only side effect is that a salesman will be calling to sell you more licenses. I have never tried to use it too many times, so I am not sure how many times you can use it before you get denied. I have never been denied using it.

Comment: If the answer above answered your question, could you please mark it as answered.

Comment: I always do ;) But I prefer to wait for either more than one answer to post or a couple of days to pass before I accept an answer. Sometimes those with valid alternative answers  are dissuaded from posting an alternative answer when one has already been accepted.